# Why wouldn't Malorie bother to put the cute toy in the bag if she told Olympia about it?

Tags: bird-box

In *Bird Box*, when Olympia saw a cute toy in a fancy bag, the following dialogue occurred:

> Olympia: What is this?
>
> Malorie: Well, **if I was just gonna tell you, I wouldn't have bothered
> putting it in this fancy... this fancy bag.** I got it on the supply
> run.

Why does Malorie say she would not have put the toy in the bag if she were going to tell Olympia about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She was giving it as a present, and [part of the tradition of presents is to hide them in a bag or wrapping](https://usvisagroup.com/american-gift-giving-customs/) so that the other person has the experience of revealing the gift.

> **How to give** – Gifts should be presented in wrapping paper or a gift bag and given when you arrive, or there may be a designated table where you can drop off your gift. It’s not uncommon for Americans to open gifts right away.